# How to use "Google Drive File Picker" API to get "Share URL" and "Manage the permission" for files?

Tags: php, api, permissions, google-drive-api

I want to use the "Google Drive File Picker" API to get "Share URL"and "Manage the permission" of the files.

I have found example here "http://stuff.dan.cx/js/filepicker/google/" to display the file list but not sure how to Manage Permission for file and Get Share URL.

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Drive File Picker Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="color:#ff0000; display: none;" id="error_file"> File is not shared. </div>
        <input type="text" id="file_url" value="" class="form-control" name="settings[url]">
    <button type="button" id="pick">Pick File</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            init = function() {
                s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient();
                s.setOAuthToken('OAUTH_TOKEN');
                s.setItemIds(['FILE_ID']);
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                auth();
                gapi.load('drive-share', init);
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="s.showSettingsDialog()">Share</button>

    <script src="filepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        function initPicker() {
            var picker = new FilePicker({
                apiKey: 'AIzaSyB8a8yohsAyEz1eZEFgt2YE-tMgACYWnVs',
                clientId: '458068379722',
                buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
                onSelect: function(file) {
                    console.log(file);                                       
                                        document.getElementById('file_url').value = file.embedLink;

                                        alert('Shared ' + file.shared);
                                        if(file.shared){
                                            alert('Share URL ' + file.embedLink);
                                        }else{                                            
                                            document.getElementById('error_file').style.display = 'block';
                                            document.getElementById('file_url').value = '';
                                        }

                }
            }); 
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyDbxa43P60iZSNUlFEquVrHV3Ir0H3FDI4"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initPicker"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can able to track file is share or not but not able to manage permission. Can any one help me to sort out this.

Thanks

Comment: Provide us with some code in order to understand the efforts you've made on figuring the solution for yourself first.

Comment: How to use "Google Drive File Picker Retrieve the share URL and able Picker" API to update/change get "Share URL" and "Manage the permissions permission" for files?

Comment: Hi aribeiro, You can take view source of the given URL for code reference. Thanks

Comment: Just a rule of thumb, Do NOT embed API keys directly in code. Keep that a secret. You can read about best practices [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037)